# Design Pattern/Workflow for a JavaScript / Ajax / PHP - Application

Tags: php, javascript, design-patterns, frameworks

I'm creating a small Web-Application with **PHP, JavaScript, Ajax and of course HTML and CSS (and  a bit jQuery).**

> Is there a Design Pattern which you recommend?

**I know MVC, but only in Java, C++.**

I'm just starting with PHP and JavaScript, and search for a source which can tell me how to use these languages correctly (**in form of how they should interact with each other**)

*My Idea is to use PHP only for DB connects and store all data "locally" in JavaScript vars, and work with them.*

**So, my questions:**

> 1. Are there any **Frameworks** (should be very small, i want to code most
>      of the functions on my own)
> 2. Is there a **book/website** which can train me to do it the right way? (or do you have any links?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of web application frameworks in `PHP` out of which few are really famous in development world. 
**cakephp** http://cakephp.org/ 
 
**codeigniter** http://codeigniter.com/ 
Both of them has rich support for MVC pattern and almost similar to `spring` and `struts` in `java` world.

Answer (score 1):

A valid answer should not refer to *Zend Framework*, *Code Igniter* or *Cake PHP*.

In my opinion [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) could be the framework you search. It is a microframework which uses some parts of *Symfony2* but is very lightweight and very easy to learn.

From the docs:

> Silex is a PHP microframework for PHP 5.3. It is built on the shoulders of Symfony2 and Pimple and also inspired by sinatra.
>
> A microframework provides the guts for building simple single-file apps. Silex aims to be:
>
> - Concise: Silex exposes an intuitive and concise API that is fun to use.
> - Extensible: Silex has an extension system based around the Pimple micro service-container that makes it even easier to tie in third party libraries.
> - Testable: Silex uses Symfony2's HttpKernel which abstracts request and response. This makes it very easy to test apps and the framework itself. It also respects the HTTP specification and encourages its proper use.

And the simplest application would just require something like this (from the docs):

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'; 

$app = new Silex\Application(); 

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) { 
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name); 
}); 

$app->run();
```

This does everything a *Controller* does and even more. You then could add [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to have a solid start for the *View* part. And for the *Model* part you could add [Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) which has a great Object Relational Mapper (ORM) and even a Object Document Mapper (ODM) if you like NoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Zend Framework. It's not "light" framework but is very modular and scalable. So you can use only few modules that you need and write rest of code by yourself. Another advantage is that is one of the most commonly used framework and have great documentation. Please see also javascript framework which can be useful for your project - http://knockoutjs.com/